# how to store multiple value in column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating job post application. In my first table the columns are This is my master table

```
ID
Position
jobDescription
minExp
maxExp
LastDate
InterviewDate
Project
HiringManager
interviewer
Primaryskills
SecondorySkills
```

and second table contains the primary skills PrimarySkill table

```
ID
PrimarySkills
```

third Table contains the secondory skills

```
ID
SecondarySkills
```

fourth Table contains the Interviewer

```
ID
Interviewer
```

the problem is that if a person have multiple skills and multiple interviewer for a job, Then how can insert the value from primary skill table, secondory skill table and interviewer table in Master table. i do not want to store value in comma separated

Comment: Create another table to hold the skills from all other table and make it slave to the master table

Comment: you maybe should give a look to tha many to many relationship.. http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: change your tables structure, and do the normalization

Answer (score 0):

Its a many to many relationship in all 3 cases. That means that you need tables between master table and the other ones.

e.g.

```
 MasterTable
 MasterID

 PrimarySkillTable
 PrimarySkillID

 PrimarySkillMasterTable
 MasterID - this key references the mastertable
 PrimarySkillID - this key references the primaryskilltable
```

All the keys are primary keys.

I hope you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the structure of your database and have many to many relationships in it.

Have a look at [this link](http://discoversql.blogspot.in/2012/04/database-modelling-many-to-many.html) which explains it with example.

For a complete detail on all relationships, visit [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) referring to which you can modify your database design accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you have 3 indipendent many to many relations, and there's only one Way to correctly solve a M:N in SQL. A third Table wich connects the Master and the Slave Table

Have a look at this little picture:

### [image: M to N example]

- Contact is a List of all Contacts
- Hobby is a List of all available Hobbys
- ContactHasHobbys creates a list of Hobbies wich are associated to a single contact

Answer (score 0):

Table 1 : InterviewMaster

---

JobID

Position

JobDescription

minExp

maxExp

LastDate

REquiredSkillSetId

---

Table 2 : InterviewDetail

---

JobID

InterviewDate

ProjectID

HiringManagerID (empid in HRpersonnel)

InterviewerId (empid in HRpersonnel)

---

Table 3 : HRPersonnel

---

EmpID

Description (InterViewer/HiringManager)

SkillSetId

---

Table 4 : SkillSet (category like .NET/JAVA)

---

SkillSet Id

Description

---

Table 5 : SkillDetails (details)

---

SkillSet Id

Description

This is just an outline.