# how to design data base for this structure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

In my first table the columns are This is my master table

```
ID
Position
jobDescription
minExp
maxExp
LastDate
InterviewDate
Project
HiringManager
interviewer
Primaryskills
SecondorySkills
```

and second table contains the primary skills PrimarySkill table

```
ID
PrimarySkills
```

third Table contains the secondory skills

```
ID
SecondarySkills
```

fourth Table contains the Interviewer

the problem is that if a person have multiple skills and multiple interviewer for a job, Then how can insert the value from primary skill table, secondary skill table and interviewer table in Master table. i do not want to store value in comma separated

Comment: you have asked the same question multiple times. [prev #1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22007540/451944) [prev #2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22009595/451944)

Comment: If you accepted the answers people took their time to provide you with, maybe you would get better answers... pay it forward.

Answer (score 0):

You create a junction table which is a third table joining the two (and something that you need if you [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data model). An example model would use these tables:

```
Person (ID, Position, ...)
Skills (ID, Skill)
PrimarySkills (Person.ID, Skill.ID)
SecondarySkills (Person.ID, Skill.ID)
```

Although splitting skills into primary and secondary might not be needed, and it might be better to add a boolean to indicate if a skill is primary or secondary, like this:

```
PersonSkills (Person.ID, Skill.ID, IsPrimary (bool))
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually do multiple links by an extra table that will just store the links, so that you can have multiple entries with the same MasterID:

table PrimarySkillsLinks:
MasterID
PrimarySkillID